# TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressValue not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, taskbar

As shown in the screenshot, my `ProgressBar1.Value` updates properly, but not my `TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressValue`:

[image]

This is the code I am using to update both:

```
void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set the Value porperty when progress changed.
    this.ProgressBar1.Value = (double)e.ProgressPercentage;

    this.TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.Normal;
    this.TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressValue = e.ProgressPercentage / 100;
}
```

How can I make my `TaskbarItemInfo` update properly?

Comment: You don't need to set `TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.Normal` every time you update the progress. Also, what I do is: `TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressValue = ProgressBar1.Value / (double)ProgressBar1.Maximum`.

Comment: @Nolonar I know, I just threw that in to let it be known that it was in fact being called.  Thanks, though.  It's a good point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
this.TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressValue = e.ProgressPercentage / 100;
```

It looks to me that you are dividing an int with another int therefore the result will be an int when a double is expected.

Simply try to suffix 100 with a "d" (making it a double) :

```
this.TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressValue = e.ProgressPercentage / 100d;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I didn't realize.  I will accept this answer as soon as possible.

Comment: I'd recommend using `100.0` when you need double, looks more kewl.

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following:

```
TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressValue = ProgressBar1.Value /(double)ProgressBar1.Maximum;
```

This ensures that the taskbar progress mirrors the progressbar's, even if `Maximum` is set to something other than `100`.

Comment: This is another good solution which would probably work.  Thanks.